# Как создать простую html форму используя Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

Я только начал знакомиться с этим фраемворком, и не понимаю как создать html форму

есть класс контроллер:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    public Result hello() {
        DynamicForm bindedForm = form().bindFromRequest();
        System.out.println(bindedForm.get("qwe"));
        return ok(index.render(bindedForm.get("qwe")));
    }

}
```

и mycontroller.scala.html:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.MyController.hello()) {
    <input type="text" name="qwe">
    <input type="submit" value="Say hello!">
}
```

в routes написал:

```
GET        /get                 controllers.MyController.hello
```

При вызове страницы ничего не происходит, просто пустая страница.
Если при вызове страницы вбить параметр ?qwe=111 в консоль все выводит.
но вопрос в том, почему не отображает текстовое поле и кнопку в моей html?

Comment: проверьте через инспект страницу, возможно они есть но вы не подключили стили ...

Comment: @Abs3akt в инспекторе тоже нет моей формы

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере ты вызываешь **index.scala.html**, а кнопка у тебя находится во вьюшке **mycontroller.scala.html**.

В контроллере последняя строчка должна быть такая:

```
return ok(mycontroller.render(bindedForm.get("qwe")));
```

Ну и вьюшка должна иметь параметр с типом `String`:

```
@(message: String)

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.hello()) {
    <input type="text" name="qwe">
    <input type="submit" value="Say hello!">
}
```